# Linking another CSS style to one table

Tags: html, css

I've got problem, because I want to have another CSS to one table in my page, but I want do it by linking this CSS.  I don't know, how to do it. Can you help me?

Comment: You can create `<style>` tag using script. What is idea behind that you do not want a link to CSS? Please add more info to your question so it has more sense, let it be more general.

Comment: I use two CSS styles on page. But in one view I have to use this 2 CSS's. I linked one CSS, which is used in all view, but this table have to be in another style, that I have definied as CSS.
I want to link CSS, but only for one block.

Comment: You really do not need another stylesheet, just add your table a specific class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this as you described but there is a convoluted way to achieve this.

In the external css page (the one which you want to now use), lets call it externalCSS, change `table{...}` to `.randomClassName, table {...}`
Now in your current html page add `class="randomClassName"` in the `table` attribute.

Also in "head" section write this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="externalCSS.css"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="currentlyUsing.css">
```

The order is important because you don't want other section of the current html page to be affected by styles mentioned in `externalCSS.css`